# What is the meaning/importance of Krampus?

Tags: discussion, design, images, fun

I've noticed some images through documents and [on site that use Krampus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149604/holiday-contest-drawing-a-picture-of-krampus-for-yule/149616) as part of a certain iconography. Where does this come from? Maybe related to GNU? But why/how?

Comment: As far as I know this is a German thing, entirely unrelated to TeX: just 'goes' with Christmas for German authors

Comment: @nilon: I am from Germany and it's not very widely known 'figure' of pagan mythology and 'carneval', used in the region of Bavaria and Austria. It's totally unrelated to TeX at at all, as Joseph Wright already stated